# Varnish set req.http.host squirreliness

Tags: wordpress, varnish

I have a site, www.whatsthatbug.com, being served via varnish/nginx/php-fpm. I am running wordpress with the wptouch pro plugin. This plugin serves a mobile version of the site to mobile users.

Here is how I doing it in Varnish. It seems to work fine if you go directly to m.whatsthatbug.com from a mobile browser, and if you go to any page other than the front page using the www.whatsthatbug.com domain. But if you go to the front page (just www.whatsthatbug.com) from a mobile browser, you are served the regular version of the site. Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Any suggestions?

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "m.whatsthatbug.com") {
      set req.http.user-agent = "iphone";
    }

    if ( req.http.user-agent ~
      "(.*iphone.*|.*ipod.*|.*incognito.*|.*webmate.*|.*android.*|.*dream.*|.*cupcake.*|.*froyo.*|.*blackberry9500.*|.*blackberry9520.*|.*blackberry9530.*|.*blackberry9550.*|.*blackberry 9800.*|.*blackberry 9780.*|.*iemobile/7.0.*|.*webos.*|.*s8000.*|.*bada.*|.*googlebot-mobile.*)" )
    {
      set req.http.host = "m.whatsthatbug.com";
    }

    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                    error 405 "Not allowed.";
            }
            return(lookup);
    }
    if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
           unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run

    varnishlog -b -o | grep Host

While you are hitting the site with the www domain, you will be able to see what the host is being set to. That *might* shed some light on what's happening. Let me know...

Comment: The site gets 20-30 hits per second, so that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Varnish 2.1 or newer (which you should), the problem is probably that the regex in your VCL is case sensitive.  A snippet from the [Varnish 2.1 FAQ](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/faq/general.html)

> Are regular expressions case sensitive or not? Can I change it?
>
> In 2.1 and newer, regular expressions are case sensitive by default. In earlier versions, they were case insensitive.
>
> To change this for a single regex in 2.1, use (?i) at the start.
>
> See the PCRE man pages for more information.

I can tell that the VCL you're using does not match for iPhone, for example - which could identify itself like this;

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3